# Using the factory method pattern: How do i instantiate new page from existing page

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

this is my index.php source, when i run it instantiate the home.php object. So index will always by default display the contents of home.php which is exactly what i want. When i click on the `Features hyperlink` it directs me to the features.php page but no content which is understandable because the features object has not been instantiated hence no output. If i do instantiate the features object then i get the contents of features.php and home.php on the index.php page which i do not want. How do i approach this,  i have tried instantiating the needed object with `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == $_GET` logic but no success. To sum it up: when i click the Features link the Features object should be instantiated and the url should reflect it eg. `test/features.php` instead of `test/index.php`.

```
<?php
    include_once 'pagefactory.php';
    include_once 'home.php';
    include_once 'features.php';
    include_once 'contact.php';

    /**
    * Class to instantiate the needed page objects
    */
    class Client {
        private $page_factory;

        function __construct($webpage) {
            $this->page_factory = new PageFactory;
            echo $this->page_factory->startFactory(new $webpage);
        }
    }
        $worker = new Client('home');

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

ive figured it out by doing the following:

```
<?php
include_once 'pagefactory.php';

function __autoload($class_name) {
    include $class_name . '.php';
}

/**
* Class to instantiate the needed page objects
*/
class Client {
    private $page_factory;

    function __construct($webpage) {
        $this->page_factory = new PageFactory;
        echo $this->page_factory->startFactory(new $webpage);
    }
}


if (isset($_GET['features'])) {
    $new_page = 'features';
    $worker = new Client($new_page);
}elseif (isset($_GET['contact'])) {
    $new_page = 'contact';
    $worker = new Client($new_page);
} else {
    $new_page = 'home';
    $worker = new Client($new_page);
}
?>
```

Ive also updated my HTML links to :

```
<li><a href="index.php" name="index">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?features" name="features">Features</a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?contact" name="features">Contact</a></li>
```

It worked perfect for me, any suggestions in any alternative methods? If so `SHARE`